# How to analyze experiment with ordinal DV measured pre-post exposure?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, pre-post-comparison

I have an experiment with 3 conditions.

The dependent variable is ordinal (Likert style item on a 1-7 scale), and it was measured at 2 time points (before and after an event that all subjects across the 3 conditions were exposed to).

I also have a few covariates of interest (categorical and continuous) that I would like to control for.

What is the best way to determine the effect of condition on the DV post-exposure, controlling for the DV pre-exposure and the covariates of interest? Would an ordinal regression be appropriate?